# How can I make an "offset" reference to a cell based on the results of an "if" in a different cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to pull the value of a cell into a summary chart but I need the cell it pulls from to be dependent on where the adjacent cell is pulling from.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do.

imagine a row of 5 cells j25:n25

depending on the results of an if evaluation, j25 will either be equal to f10 or i10.

k25 needs to be equal to the cell 3 columns to the right of the cell that j25 gets its value from... in this scenario either i10 or l10

l25 needs to pull from the cell 3 columns to the right of the cell that k25 pulled its value from ... in this scenario l10 or o10

and so and so on.

After doing some research it looks like I might be able to do this with the formulatext function if I had excel 2013, but I'm still on 2010

Any suggestions?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Excel 2010, if you're willing to hide a helper cell somewhere, it can be done as follows. In the pics, the green cell tells which cell should go into J25. The yellow cell just contains the corresponding cell address. Unfortunately, to do this you also have to keep J26 in sync with J25 (same cell addresses).
[image]

The results look like this:
[image]

The values J25 - M25 all change depending on the value of F1. Additional cells are just a matter of dragging M25 to the right.

For easy reference, the formula in K25... is `=OFFSET(INDIRECT($J26),0,(COLUMN()-COLUMN($J25))*3)`

You could format J26 so it isn't visible and/or put it in a different part of the worksheet altogether.

As an aside, it looks like it could be done in 2013 with `FORMULATEXT` as you thought.

Comment: Alas, as I said in the OP, I don not have excel 2013... just 2010

Comment: @MSchoenike - My wording was bad. I believe my solution works in Excel 2010. It does not use `FORMULATEXT`--I just mentioned it because it **might** work in 2013. I will edit the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: My apologies.  I was skimming trying to do too many things at once.  Your solution worked beautifully.  Thanks.